# Reading Windows Unicode files on Android

Tags: android, unicode

I just found out that Android can correctly read in a file which is encoded using Windows ANSI (or the so-called multi-byte encoding) and convert it to Java Unicode strings. But it fails when reading a Unicode file. It seems that Android is reading it in a byte-by-byte fashion. A Unicode string "ABC" in the file would be read in to a Java String of length 6, and the characters are 0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathname));
String str = in.readLine();
```

Please, is there a way to read Windows Unicode files correctly on Android? Thank you.

[Edited]

Experiements: I saved two Chinese characters "難哪" in two Windows text files:

```
ANSI.txt -- C3 F8 AD FE
UNICODE.txt -- FF FE E3 96 EA 54
```

Then I put these files to Emulator's SD card, and I used the following program to read them in: (Notice that the locale of the Emulator has already been set to zh_TW).

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/ANSI.txt"));
String szLine = in.readLine();
int n = szLine.length(), j, i;
in.close();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    j = szLine.charAt(i);
```

Here is what I saw on the Emulator:

```
ANSI.txt -- FFFD FFFD FFFD
UNICODE.txt -- FFFD FFFD FFFD FFFD 0084
```

Apparantly Android (or Java) is unable to properly decode the Chinese characters. So, how do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FileReader apparently assumes that the encoding will be ASCII-compatible. (Could expect UTF-8 or any of the older ASCII extensions).

Also, it is not a "Unicode file" - it is an "UTF-16 encoded file".

You will have to use a `StreamReader` and specify the encoding yourself:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathname), "UTF-16LE"));
```

You should also really read [that article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - it seems to me that there is a lot that you misunderstand about character sets and encoding.

Comment: Thanks, InputStreamReader is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code. 
Normally Window base Ascii file that within the chinese words
may not be correct process under android system. 
It's normally default to use the UTF8 format in stream Process.

Once you place a Window base Ascii file that within chinese words into Android system.
the normal stream process can't correct recognize the part of chinese.

following code, can correct parser String from Window Base Acsii text file that within chinese words
 that put at Android System SD or Asset folder.

It's very simple just Use "BIG5" format decoder , at InputStreamReader Ojbect.

I have been verified. It's working well. Try it !! 
FYI. KNC.

```
String pathname="AAA.txt";
BufferedReader inBR;
inBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathname), "BIG5"));
String sData="";

while ((sData  = inBR.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A Unicode string "ABC" in the file would be read in to a Java String of length 6, and the characters are 0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00.

How are you getting the length? What you have described is absolutely correct for a Java `String`. Java strings are UTF-16 (i.e., Unicode). This means that `ABC` will be stored in a Java string exactly as you describe (`0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00`).

The String 'length', however, as returned by `int String.length()` will be 3 even though it is 6 bytes long.

Comment: thanks for the reponse. String.length() returns 6. Here is some more details: In Windows, there is a file with the following bytes: 0xff, 0xfe, 0x41, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00. I put this file to SD card and use the above code to read it, the resulting Java string's length is 8. Using String.charAt() to exmine the string, I get the following 8 integers: 0xfffd, 0xfffd, 0x0041, 0x0000, 0x0042, 0x0000, 0x0043, 0x0000. If the file contains double-byte characters like 3 Chinese characters, then the Java string length is even weirder: 7! (Device's locale has been set to Chinese)

Comment: (continued) So, it seems that Java's FileReader is unable to handle Unicoded files. Is there anyway to properly handle Windows Unicoded files on Android? Thank you.